# Detectar texto entre corchetes y paréntesis en php

Tags: php, preg-match

¿Como puedo detectar el contenido de todos los corchetes que abren y cierran [], y seguido el contenido de unos paréntesis ()?
(Los corchetes siempre estaran juntos a los paréntesis)

**Teniendo el siguiente texto:**

```
El siguiente texto [tiene](contenido) que [deseo](obtener).
```

**Busco obtener:**

```
array("tiene" => "contenido","deseo" => "obtener")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias intentar esto con expresiones regulares de PHP:

```
$cadena = "El siguiente texto [tiene](contenido) que [deseo](obtener).";
$salida = [];

preg_match_all('/\[+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]/', $cadena, $primeras);//Obtengo las palabras encerradas en corchetes
preg_match_all('/\(+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)/', $cadena, $segundas);//Obtengo las palabras encerradas en Parentesis

//recorro los corchetes
for($i=0; $i<count($primeras[0]);$i++){
    $a = str_replace(["[","]","(",")"],"",$primeras[0][$i]);//Elimino los caracteres no deseados []
    $b = str_replace(["[","]","(",")"],"",$segundas[0][$i]);//Elimino los caracteres no deseados ()
    $salida[$a] = $b;//Agrego al array de salida
}
var_dump($salida);
```

esto imprime:
array(2) { ["tiene"]=> string(9) "contenido" ["deseo"]=> string(7) "obtener" }

al final deberas validar que las cantidades encontradas coincidan o vas a tener problemas, por ejemplo conj una cadena asi:

**`El siguiente texto [tiene](contenido) que [deseo](obtener) [notiene] [sitiene](contenido).`**

esto no retornaría un error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in Cindex.php on line 19
```

espero te oriente.

Saludos